# TV Pilot or Movie, 80s, misfit team with powers

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to identify a show I saw on TV in the 80s (in the US).  It was a single viewing, and felt like a television pilot rather than a standalone movie; ISTR the final scene dangled the possibility of further adventures.

The plot resolved around a handful of people with powers who are teamed up to fight something bad.  It had a "misfits forced to team up" feel to it.

I remember two of the specific powers, and one climactic scene.

One of the powered had Flash-like speed; he'd simply blur from place to place when he wanted to move fast.

One of the powered was a cryogenic man.  He'd been a worker employed by Howard Hughes, and had fallen into a cryogenic chamber Hughes had been experimenting with, and was preserved in it for 50 years.  When he came out, he remained frozen, and wore a thermal suit to protect himself and anything he touched.

In one of the climactic scenes, the heroes have to get into *facility*, but the only way in is through a corridor which has been turned into a vortex of spinning water (like a tube made of moving water).  Cryogenic man takes off his glove, sticks his hand in the water, and freezes the entire tube solid, allowing the heroes to cross - but sacrificing himself in the process.

Comment: Misfits of Science. Courtney Cox, before friends. Swirling tunnel was a giveaway... same set piece used for bionic man and the Sasquatch episodes.

Comment: @DarrenVancouver yeah, the swirling tunnel. LMAO. Then after that being "the only way in" when they're done with the mission, they just escape through a hatch in the roof.  Like, why couldn't they have gone in that way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Could it be *[Misfits of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_of_Science)*?

> The show concerned super-powered humans and their madcap adventures. The team is formed by Dr. Billy Hayes, a research scientist at the Humanidyne Institute who specializes in "human anomalies". He works with shrinking Dr. Elvin "El" Lincoln, and together they recruit electrically powered Johnny Bukowski, a rock-and-roll musician, and Gloria Dinallo, a telekinetic teen.

The cryogenically powered man would be Arnold Beifneiter:

> Mickey Jones as Arnold "Beef"/"Ice Man" Beifneiter, who got his power to freeze anything he touches from placing himself in an experimental cryogenic suspended animation unit back in 1937 due to grief caused by the loss of his beloved Amelia Earhart. The team drives around in an ice-cream truck (International Metro Mite M-800) because the lumbering and now rather simple-minded Ice Man dies if he gets too warm, so they keep him in the freezer. Beef only appears in the pilot episode due to legal objections from Marvel Comics who published a similarly-named character in X-Men, but the characters continue to use the ice-cream truck.

Found with a search for *80s tv series ice powers superspeed*

### Opening Sequence

Comment: Got it in one, Mr. Garibaldi.  Now that I know there are episodes I'll try to track them down...

Comment: With Courtney Cox from Friends, and Max Wright (RIP) from Alf!

Comment: @gowenfawr Do yourself a favor and don't.  Just let it live in your memory as a pleasant bit of your childhood.  I loved this show as a kid.  I got the pilot on VHS about 15 years ago and let's just say it did not age well at all

Answer (score 13):

It's a bit of a long shot but could this be [*Misfits of Science*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088568/?ref_=ttls_li_tt) (1985-1986)?

> Superhero series about a group of young mutants who worked for an American thinktank fighting crime. Elvin could shrink to a size of eight inches, Gloria possessed telekinetic powers, and Johnny B was able to fire lightning bolts from his hands. Their leader was Dr. Hayes.

It doesn't match exactly but does seem to be somewhat close. The first episode, the pilot, is ["Deep Freeze"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089602/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) and it does sound somewhat similar to what you remember.

> Drs. Hayes and Lincoln are researchers in biological oddities for the Humanidyne company. When they find a man still alive after being frozen for 50 years, their greedy boss fires them and takes the Iceman to use for military experiments. Left without jobs, Hayes and Lincoln decide to get a group of "freaks" (including a telekinetic 17-year-old and a rock guitarist who shoots lightning from his hands) together to rescue the Iceman and stop their boss' reckless experiments.

---

I found this by Googling `80's tv show superspeed` which turned up the IMdb list: [Best Super Power TV Shows](Best Super Power TV Shows). I then looked through the list to find something that sounded right.

Comment: I think I lucked out with a "fastest gun" answer. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Aye seems like it but you also got a description for the frozen character so it was already a +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

Misfits of Science. Courtney Cox, before friends. Swirling tunnel was a giveaway... same set piece used for bionic man and the Sasquatch episodes.[image]